# vb.net combine to array with the same range

Tags: arrays, vb.net

if i have an array like this

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

and a second array like this

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

how to creat new array from the first tow arrays so the new array  be like this

```
AA
BB
CC
DD
EE
```

i try this

```
 Dim urls() As String
    For i As Int32 = 0 To array1.Length - 1
        urls = array1.Select(Function(o) array2(i) & o).ToArray()
 next
```

but the output was like this

```
EA
EB
EC
ED
EE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
    Dim array1() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
    Dim array2() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}


    Dim urls() As String
    urls = array1.Select(Function(o, p) o & array2(p)).ToArray()
```

Hope that helps....

Answer (score 2):

you are using for loop and lambda query both which shouldn't be the case.
Try the below code

```
Dim urls() As String
urls = array1.Select(Function(item, index) item & array2(index)).ToArray()
```

**OR**

```
Dim urls() As String
urls = array1.Zip(array2, Function(x, y) x & y).ToArray()
```